# simple way to drop milliseconds from python datetime.datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

My colleague needs me to drop the milliseconds from my python timestamp objects in order to comply with the old POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1-1988) standard. The tortured route that accomplishes this task for me is as follows:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Is there a simpler way to end up with a datetime.datetime object for mongoDB than this?

Comment: now = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) method -

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 18, 9, 50, 20)
```

Comment: This question is old, but I would like to add that you would need to do something like this if you intend to keep milliseconds

`now = datetime.utcnow()`
`now.replace(microsecond=round(now.microsecond, -3))`

Comment: It may be old, but I'm about to pass 100 upvotes! So perhaps the source documentation remains too vague, 7 years later?

Comment: yep 2023 still works