# Checking for equality of multiple fields of two datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I want to make sure two datetime objects have the same date and time up to the seconds.

```
from datetime import datetime

time_a = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 3, 14, 15, 9)
time_b = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 3, 14, 15, 10)
```

I can't just do `assert time_a == time_b`, since they have different microseconds.

I could do this with multiple assert statements:

```
assert time_a.year == time_b.year
assert time_a.month == time_b.month
assert time_a.day == time_b.day
assert time_a.hour == time_b.hour
assert time_a.minute == time_b.minute
assert time_a.second == time_b.second
```

But this is a bit repetitive. Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487732/simple-way-to-drop-milliseconds-from-python-datetime-datetime-object  

Try: `assert time_a.replace(microsecond=0) == time_b.replace(microsecond=0)`

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_a = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 3, 14, 15, 9).replace(microsecond=0)
time_b = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 3, 14, 15, 10).replace(microsecond=0)

assert time_a == time_b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the difference in time is less than one second using `timedelta`.

That is,

```
abs(time_a-time_b) < timedelta(seconds=1)
```

This is true whenever the absolute value of the difference is less than one second, so it effectively checks for equality up to the seconds. This has the advantage of keeping the original microsecond level information intact in the `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Is removing microseconds will solve your problem:

```
time_a.replace(microsecond=0) == time_b.replace(microsecond=0)
```