# format error in python string to time conversion~

Tags: python

Currently, test 32 is the str type.
I would like to express the str type of test32 in time data. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss method...
However, time data '22/03/0823:33:55.256' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' error occurs. Is there any way?

```
    for z in data:
        if 'D:\System\iUTILITY\Tool\Curver\ToolBox\STG\i02-K01_S1_CEC_Update_Monintor_Analysis.xpsp' in z:
            test30 = z.split(' ')[0:2]
            test31 = ''.join(test30)
            
            test32 = test31.split(',')[0]
            print(type(test32))
            test33 = datetime.datetime.strptime(test32, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
            print(test33)
            # print(test32)
```

Comment: you could use `try:  convert with one format` `except: convert with another format`

Answer (score 0):

To parse the date `22/03/0823:33:55.256`, you need to use format `%y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S.%f`, like this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('22/03/0823:33:55.256', '%y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S.%f')
# Ouptut: datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 8, 23, 33, 55, 256000)
```

According to the document, `%y` stands for the year without century, and `%f` stands for the microsecond. Here's the document:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: I want to erase .%f. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "want to erase '.%f'"? Do you mean to ignore the microsecond in the datetime object?

Comment: yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You can do it by calling `replace(microsecond=0)` method on the datetime object. Here's a link to more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487732/simple-way-to-drop-milliseconds-from-python-datetime-datetime-object